# how to make req.query only accepts date format like yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to ask how can I make my req.query only accepts date format like this YYYY-MM-DD and not just random number because my code still accepting numbers like "123456" in query.

Comment: Do some validations use library such as [joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0)

Comment: is there any other way? i don't want to use library

Comment: Can you provide an example route you have? for an example: `myawesomehost:3000/api/v1/users?year=2021&month=1&date=21`

Comment: my route is like this /api/v1/days/?day=2021/01/20

Comment: If it's invalid, what you expected? NotFound response or BadRequest response?

Comment: just an invalid format. my only validation is if its undefined but when insert random number it still accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code below:

```js
const isValidDate = !(new Date('2021/01/20').toString().toLowerCase().includes('invalid'));

if (isValidDate) {
  console.log('Valid Date');
} else {
  console.log('InValid Date');
}
```

Comment: its false when I input 2021/01/20. It should be true right?

Comment: The code is working as intended however when I used it to my code base its not giving the right info. Here's my code.

const { day } = req.query;
const isValidDate = !(new Date(day).toString().toLowerCase().includes('invalid'));

if (!isValidDate) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Please enter a date in this format yyyy-mm-dd'
            })

Comment: can you explain to me this? pls so I don't ask again :D

Comment: the code you made if its okay with you. i'm fairly new to backend sorry.

Comment: I think you can console req.params.day and see the result. Make sure it's same with you expected.